# I want to extend my partition

Tags: 12.10, server, partitioning, windows-7

I am currently dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10. I have 500GB with 300GB free space on my Windows, and have a 100GB on my Ubuntu. I want to move 200GB from my Windows partition to my Ubuntu Partition. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the layout of your hard disk. Go to Disks application, select your hard disk, take a screenshot and post it here

Answer (score 1):

For windows follow [these](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) instructions.

For Ubuntu:

Open a terminal window and
type `df -h` to get the size of the root volume, then type `sudo resize2fs /dev/<disk – mine was sda1>`, then after a few minutes and the operation is completed type `df-h` again to verify your root volume has increased.

Do windows first.